# how to make diamond shape using python

Tags: python

[i want like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2rwr.png)

how to make diamond shape using python

```
n = int(input("n ="))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(2*n-i-1):
        print (" ",end="")
    for k in range(2*i+1):
        print(i,end="")
    print()

for a in range(n-2,-1,-1):
    for b in range(n-a+i):
        print (" ",end="")
    for c in range(2*a+1):
        print(n,end="")
    print()
```

but the result is

```
         0
        111
       22222
      3333333
     444444444
      5555555
       55555
        555
         5
```

Comment: In `for k in range(2*i+1): print(i,end="")` you found out how to write consecutive characters for a filled shape. What should it take to have a hollow shape? Just write `i` before, then `2*i-1` spaces (` `), then `i` again (with a condition).

Comment: Please edit the text of your desired outcome into your question rather than posting an image or linking to an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Function declarations
def get_spaces(number: int):
    spaces = ""

    for i in range(number):
        spaces += " "

    return spaces


# Get input.
n = int(input("n = "))

# Figure out how wide and tall the diamond will be.
dimension = n * 2 - 1

# Keeps track of the next number to print.
num_to_print = 1

# Outer loop controls what row we're working on.
for row in range(dimension):
    # Calculates how many spaces need to go before the number to keep the
    # diamond shape.
    padding_spaces = abs(n - row - 1)

    # Prints the first number that appears for each row.
    print(f"{get_spaces(padding_spaces)}{num_to_print}", end="")
    # Increments the number to print and loops it back to 0
    # every time it hits 10.
    num_to_print = (num_to_print + 1) % 10

    # Prints the second number that appears for each row if applicable.
    if padding_spaces < (n - 1):
        # Calculates how many spaces need to go between the two numbers
        # inside the diamond.
        inner_diamond_spacing = 1 + ((n - 2) - padding_spaces) * 2
        print(f"{get_spaces(inner_diamond_spacing)}{num_to_print}", end="")
        num_to_print = (num_to_print + 1) % 10

    # Moves to the next row.
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two loops and keep track on the number to print with another variable

```
num = 1
print(' ' * (n - 1), num, sep='')
for i in range(n - 1):
    print(' ' * (n - i - 2), (num := (num + 1)) % 10, ' ' * (2 * i + 1), (num := (num + 1)) % 10, sep='')
for i in range(n - 1, 1, -1):
    print(' ' * (n - i), (num := (num + 1)) % 10, ' ' * (2 * i - 3), (num := (num + 1)) % 10, sep='')
print(' ' * (n - 1), (num + 1) % 10, sep='')
```

`n=3`

```
  1
 2 3
4   5
 6 7
  8
```

`n=5`

```
    1
   2 3
  4   5
 6     7
8       9
 0     1
  2   3
   4 5
    6
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple version with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and simple arithmetic:

```
from itertools import count

def diamond(n):
    c = count(1)
    for i in range(2*n-1):
        x = abs(i-n+1)
        print('-'*x, str(next(c)%10 if 0<i<(2*n-2) else ''),
              '⋅'*(2*(n-x-1)-1), str(next(c)%10), sep='')
```

Demo:

*NB. using `-` and `⋅` as chars instead of   to better see the logic*

```
diamond(2)
-1
2⋅3
-4

diamond(3)
--1
-2⋅3
4⋅⋅⋅5
-6⋅7
--8

diamond(5)
----1
---2⋅3
--4⋅⋅⋅5
-6⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅7
8⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅9
-0⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅1
--2⋅⋅⋅3
---4⋅5
----6
```